# entry is not defind error showing while i use a class to define the binding function

Tags: python, tkinter, development-environment, software-design, tkinter-entry

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqYzu.png)

I am facing this error which shows in the screenshot, when I move my bind function into a class or another module

showing as entry is not defined.. it worked fine without a class

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("speed entering calculator")

class Methods1:
    i=0

    #function for enter
def entering(self,a):
        global i #to inform this function that i is global variable
        try:     # try and exception used to print message if error happen

            value1=int (entry1.get()) #entry1.get()is used to get values which entered in entry box
            value1=i + value1
            label1['text']=value1
            i=value1

        except ValueError as ve:
            print(f'only integer')



    entry1.delete(0, END) # used to clear entry box




ob=Methods1()











#creating canvas
canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(root, height=400 , width=400, bg="black")
canvas1.pack()

#making entry box for values
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(root, justify="center", )
canvas1.create_window(200,140,height=100,width=100, window=entry1)

value = "the values should be shown here"
label1=Label(root, text =value, height=10) 
label1.pack()




#binding enter key as adding
root.bind('<Return>',ob.entering)






root.mainloop()
```

i am not really good at programming language. so I hope I could find a solution from here

Comment: please provide a [mre] (read how to make one, otherwise it is hard to understand your issue) and fix your indents, also if you don't understand classes don't try making programs with them, first learn how they function then use them in code, for now I can suggest that you stick to the functional approach until you understand classes.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was attempting to reference objects before they had been declared.

Rearranging the code solved that problem.

The other main problem was the importation method used for `tkinter`

Changing that to a standard form solved that.

Finally `i` in `class` needed to be changed to `self.i`

It now works.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("speed entering calculator")

#creating canvas
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, height = 400, width = 400, bg = "black")
canvas1.pack()

#making entry box for values
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, justify = "center")
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, height = 100, width = 100, window = entry1)

value = "the values should be shown here"
label1 = tk.Label(root, text = value, height = 10) 
label1.pack()

class Methods1:
    i = 0

    def entering(self, a):
        try:
            value1 = int(entry1.get()) 
            value1 = self.i + value1
            label1['text'] = value1
            self.i = value1
        except ValueError as ve:
            print(f'only integer')
        entry1.delete(0, tk.END) # used to clear entry box

ob = Methods1()

#binding enter key as adding
root.bind('<Return>', ob.entering)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey .. what's the problem with the importation method that I used?  thank you

Comment: Well basically the first import imports `tkinter` by name while the second imports everything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in this code, not least the formatting, but when I had corrected the indents I did not see an error that `entry1` was undefined. However, the variable `i` is undefined and the method is static which means it shouldn't be in a class anyway. The code seemed to work once I made a few changes (removing the function from the class and then deleting the class overall). Here is the code that worked:

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("speed entering calculator")

i = 0


# function for enter
def entering(event):

    global i
    # try and exception used to print message if error happen
    try:
        # get values which are entered in entry box
        value1 = int(entry1.get())
        value1 = i + value1
        label1['text'] = value1
        i = value1
    except ValueError:
        print("only integer")

    # clear entry box
    entry1.delete(0, END)


# creating canvas
canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(root, height=400, width=400, bg="black")
canvas1.pack()

# making entry box for values
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(root, justify="center")
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, height=100, width=100, window=entry1)

value = "the values should be shown here"
label1 = Label(root, text=value, height=10)
label1.pack()

# binding enter key as adding
root.bind('<Return>', entering)

root.mainloop()
```